# Targets or Target's?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

so I am making a troll website thing (hard to explain). But I have a text box and the label says `"Enter Target's Name"`. I was wondering if my use of the `apostrophe` was correct or should it be `"Enter Targets Name"`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"the target's name" = "the name of the target"

When it has the sense of "of", then an apostrophe is used.

"The targets are in sight." has no apostrophe; the final "s" just makes it plural.

Comment: Hello, Michael. Please take a look at the Help Center, and at other posts, to see whether this question is a good fit for the site's format. Answering questions that are too basic encourages a glut of them.